# Буква ижица

Tags: лингвистика

Как читалась буква ижица?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Буква ижица, последняя буква дореволюционной кириллицы, означала звук И в некоторых словах греческого происхождения (синод, миро). Происходит она от греческой же буквы ипсилон.